# SQL BETWEEN not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following statement being run on an oracle database.

```
SELECT br.Number
  FROM Billing_History br 
 WHERE TRUNC(br.History_Date) BETWEEN to_date('01-Jan-99', 'DD-Mon-YY HH:MI:SS') 
                                  AND to_date('11-May-99', 'DD-Mon-YY HH:MI:SS')
```

There are definitely records in that table that fall between those dates. And they all have a Number that goes with them, but for some reason this isn't returning any Numbers. It's returning nothing at all.

The dates in the database are in this format '01-Jan-11'. So it seems like I'm putting the dates in the correct format too. Do you see anything wrong with the SQL I wrote?

Comment: I fail to see how 01-Jan-11 is between 01-Jan-99 and 11-May-99...

Comment: What type is column br.History_Date?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth that is just an example to illustrate the format that the dates are in. They are not that exact date. The column type is Date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not the time component of the format model, it's the 'YY' component, which would mean in your year is converted to 2099, not 1999. Try this to illustrate:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('01-Apr-99','DD-Mon-YY'),'DD-Mon-YYYY') thedate
       FROM dual;

THEDATE
-----------
01-Apr-2099

SQL>
```

Either use RR or YYYY as a format model component for year when using 20th century dates.

Edit:

You make the statement "The dates in the database are in this format '01-Jan-11'." This is a common, but incorrect, interpretation of dates in Oracle. DATE fields are always stored in the same [internal format](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i1847). It's all about how you use the format model in conversion functions that dictates how the data is converted to/from internal format.

Comment: +1: This is the trouble - as would be spotted by using the TO_DATE expressions in the select-list of a query from dual.

Answer (score 5):

Use RR in your date format instead of YY. It is probably picking up those dates as 2099 instead of 1999.

```
SELECT br.Number FROM Billing_History br WHERE  
TRUNC(br.History_Date) BETWEEN to_date('01-Jan-99', 'DD-Mon-RR HH:MI:SS') 
AND to_date('11-May-99', 'DD-Mon-RR HH:MI:SS')
```

Comment: +1: This is the trouble - as would be spotted by using the TO_DATE expressions in the select-list of a query from dual.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the time part from the second `to_date` parameter:

```
to_date('11-May-99', 'DD-Mon-YY')
```

Or even better:

```
to_date('11-05-1999', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

This is more robust as it is language agnostic and doesn't need to guess the century.